# R: assignment by index with a list of lists

Tags: r, list

Suppose I create an empty list of 3 elements, then I want to fill the first and third element with the same copy of another list. Can't seem to figure out how to do this.

```
z = vector('list', 3)
z[c(1, 3)] = 'a'
z # works fine 
[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "a"

z[c(1, 3)] = list('a', 'b')
z # doesn't work

[[1]]
[1] "a"

[[2]]
NULL

[[3]]
[1] "b"
```

Desired result is that both [[1]] and [[3]] contain the list('a','b'). Saw some other posts, but those have to do with retrieving values, not assigning them.

Comment: Try `z[c(1, 3)] <- list(list('a', 'b'))`

Comment: Ah, thanks that works!